# Intercept Ethernet packets before they reach kernel

Tags: c, linux, tcp, linux-kernel, network-programming

I'd like to receive raw Ethernet packets for two different scenarios:

1. Receive a copy so it still reaches the Kernel
2. Intercept the packets so the Kernel never sees them and I implement the logic.

From Googling I found this:

```
sock_raw = socket(AF_PACKET , SOCK_RAW , htons(ETH_P_ALL));
```

I think this makes the Kernel send a copy, i.e. scenario #1?

**Q: How would I implement the second scenario, to intercept the packet and deprive the Kernel?**

My goal is to intercept packets from the network card driver and process them through my own Ethernet, IP and TCP stack.

I'm aware this isn't trivial. I'm fine reading RFC specifications and writing code, my weak area is understanding how the Linux Kernel works (although if I'm bypassing it, that might be less of a problem?).

Any advice/tips/links are most-welcome.

Comment: "_'d like to receive raw Ethernet packets_" That would be "_ethernet frames_." The Preamble and SoF delimiter of the ethernet packet are handled by the hardware and never seen in the network stack. Even the FCS of the frame is often stripped off before the frame is into the software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your Kernel is in charge of your network card. It literally is the only thing in your system that knows how to get packets (frames) from the card!

> My goal is to intercept packets from the network card driver

The network card driver *is* the kernel.

You hence *cannot* intercept a packet before it reaches the kernel, unless you completely remove the network card from the control of the kernel. (that exists, e.g., in the shape of DPDK, but I'm very sure you're not interested in writing a userland driver for your card) And then you'd still be stuck with the problem of getting the packet *into* the kernel afterwards.

So, what you want makes no sense.

What you probably instead want to do is write a filter that runs *within* the kernel space. eBPF makes that possible. But it's *in* the kernel.

---

> I think this makes the Kernel send a copy, i.e. scenario #1?

No, that means your program is now listening on the raw ethernet device for frames, which you get, after they've gone through the kernel. But they will not be copied to the IP stack.

Comment: I'd suggest checking out DPDK, which can solve your challenge rather easily. DPDK requires some learning, but essentially, it allows a userspace process to directly access and control the network card (NIC). DPDK's KNI example application seems to be exactly what you need (https://doc.dpdk.org/guides-18.08/sample_app_ug/kernel_nic_interface.html). The KNI application sees incoming packets first, and can choose to forward them back into the kernel, which can then send the packets to other userspace applications.

Comment: @TSG I mention DPDK! DPDK is a solution if you can spare a full CPU core for the polling – that is assuming OP's network card is supported by it. It's usually not an interesting architecture for non-dataplane applications.

Comment: Correct. However, DPDK's list of supported NICs is very impressive. Of course, not all NICs support the same feature set, but I think the KNI has very few requirements. Also, I commented on your answer instead of a separate comment since you already mentioned DPDK.

Comment: :D thanks! Yeah, it's quite large, but it's typically not the consumer, Realtek-grade NICs you would expect OP to have if they don't mention it. Mostly, embedded-market CPU-integrated things, and datacenter/10GE stuff. Mostly, what you need is just clean support for usage under an IOMMU.

Comment: @TSG What if I don't want the kernel involved at all? Is DPDK able to communicate to the NIC without the kernel?

Comment: You need the kernel to set up the PCIe/memory mapping correctly. But other than that, it stays out of the way. That's the point of DPDK, @intrigued_66. Again, you need a network card that is supported by DPDK. And, yet again, there's zero indication you gain anything from doing this outside the kernel :) TSG probably won't recommend DPDK for applications where you need packets to actually go back through the kernel, which is *exactly* what you're describing in the question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hi, given the time since I asked the original question, my previous comment is slightly different. I no-longer care about sending packets back to the kernel afterwards, so just use DPDK?

Comment: no. Just use the kernel. You do not need DPDK.

Comment: @intrigued_66, DPDK is one solution. See, the kernel generally contains a module/driver for communicating with the NIC, and uses the driver for both the control path (setting up the NIC) and the data path (send/recv packets). DPDK removes the kernel from the datapath entirely, allowing the user program to directly send/recv packets. This is obviously essential for datacenter applications which require the performance. From my experience with DPDK, it is a mature ecosystem, but the non-standard approach means that it might not always work for you, or make your life harder.

Comment: Using kernel APIs (like @MarcusMüller) suggests can be both more restrictive (since you are stuck with kernel APIs) and more standardized. Using the kernel APIs allows you to use a mature codebase, standard APIs and benefit from compatibility and portability. Finding online support might be easier (bcoz standard APIs) and harder (bcoz most applicable support will focus on SOCK_STREAM). Finally, depends on you and your use case. I have personally enjoyed the amazing capabilities of DPDK when I needed to use it, but I cannot vouch that it's the best for your use case.

Comment: @TSG Please forgive the late response. I like the architecture behind DPDK but I do not like the manual setup required: Linux commands/installation, unhooking device drivers, having to allocate huge pages etc. I did find a simple DPDK guide but it was from 2017 and started to become a little dated. If you do know any good resources I would like to try again. Initially I only want to send and receive packets on the same local host.

Comment: I'm not sure what the best solution for you will be. There is a guide on the DPDK website (http://core.dpdk.org/doc/quick-start/). However, the setup is going to require some degree of understanding. If you are not comfortable with this setup, DPDK might not be the best for you.

Comment: @TSG but if that setup is beyond their understanding, then they will have a hard time dealing with network cards and ethernet frames, anyway.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, agreed. DPDK might be the perfect tool for the task, but not very accessible.

Comment: @TSG I do maintain that intrigued_66 has not shown any indication they would have any benefit from not using the kernel's full network stack, so the perfect tool would quite possibly just using standard `AF_INET` sockets, and if that doesn't suffice, sprinkling a minimum amount of kernel-side BPF packet handling on top.